# I'm trying to create a spinner in a Fragment and fill it using ArrayList but the app keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragment-manager

This is my first time using Fragments in Android and I'm trying to create a spinner and fill it using an ArrayList. My app has 3 buttons on the main screen, the first button replaces the FrameLayout in the activity with this fragment but as soon as I press it the app crashes.
I have to make two other fragments but I can't even make this one work first!
This is for a project.
Please help. I'm including the XML and JAVA for the fragment down below.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Book">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BOOK HOTELS"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="316dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="572dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
package com.example.hotelfragmentexercise;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Book extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
   Spinner spinner;
   ArrayList<Hotels> hotelsList = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayAdapter<Hotels> hotelsArrayAdapter;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);
       fillData();
       spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

       hotelsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Hotels>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hotelsList);

       hotelsArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(hotelsArrayAdapter);
       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

       //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);
       return view;
   }

   public void fillData(){
       hotelsList.add(new Hotels("Town Inn Suites", "The Town Inn Suites is centrally located in downtown Toronto. Close to the shops of Bloor and only steps away from transportation at Bloor and Yonge.", 233.99));
       hotelsList.add(new Hotels("Times Square Suites Hotel", "Times Square Suites apartment-style hotel has been pleasing business travelers, couples and families for many years. Each of the 42 suites has a full kitchen,washer/dryer, fireplace, HD TV and blu ray player.", 294.78));
       hotelsList.add(new Hotels("Best Western The Westerly Hotel", "Courtenay's Only Full-Service Hotel Centrally Located in the Heart of the Comox Valley our location offers convenient access to all that Comox Valley has to offer. Our property features 66 guestrooms, inclusive of our 36 room Mountainside wing. ", 213.71));
       hotelsList.add(new Hotels("YMCA Hotel Vancouver", "YWCA Hotel Vancouver offers a warm welcome to all travellers and is a comfortable, safe and affordable place to stay at the heart of downtown's arts and entertainment scene. All rooms are private and there’s a choice to suit your needs and budget - from single rooms to quints.", 133.84));
       hotelsList.add(new Hotels("Grand Inn & Residence", "Settle in for a relaxing, just-like-home experience at one of Grande Prairie’s premier all-suite, extended stay hotels - Podollan Rez-idence. Designed and built to meet the needs of today’s discerning traveller, our all-suite property features beautifully appointed studio, one- and two-bedroom suites with fully equipped kitchens, and luxury living rooms with leather furnishings and wood floors.", 201.53));
   }

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

   }
}
```

Comment: it's because you are referencing different spinner which is not in your fragment_book. change this line  spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);
   fillData();
   spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayList<String> hotelsNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < hotelsList.size(); i++) {
        hotelsNames.add(hotelsList.get(i).getName());
    }


   hotelsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hotelsNames);

   hotelsArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   spinner.setAdapter(hotelsArrayAdapter);
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

   //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);
   return view;
}
```

And, change your ArrayAdapter Types to String from Hotels as it will return hotels names rather than hotel objects.i.e.

```
ArrayAdapter<Hotels> hotelsArrayAdapter /*change this line to*/ ->  ArrayAdapter<String> hotelsArrayAdapter /*this one*/
```